# Advertise in WPF application?

Tags: wpf, desktop-application, desktop, ads

Is that possible? I know that services like Google Ads prohibit advertising in desktop applications. Is there a service that supports the WPF/.NET?

Comment: you could try using affiliate links

Comment: "I know that services like Google Ads prohibit advertising in desktop applications."

How do you know this? I read their license end to end and I can't find anything prohibiting ads in a desktop application. Can your first provide a reference for your statement?

Comment: Ok, I found a link. However, Google is a little misleading here. There is nothing in the AdSense Terms and Conditions that says this, but they have additional information (that you never actually had to agree to like you had to agree to the Terms and Conditions). See it here: http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1346295#Ads_in_a_software_application

Answer (score 3):

First,adsense being not allowed to be used in desktop apps , You can look for other advertising networks. There are other ad networks like amazon associates , .. etc . You can search for them according to the domains ex: banking, retails . You can look for/contact them for their terms and conditions on desktop usage.

And not all of them would provide you an API for .Net.
If amazon is allowed for desktop usage: Look into this 
[API](http://aws.amazon.com/code/Product-Advertising-API/3941)

Secondly , w.r.t the technical aspects of WPF. 
You can have a website built to inject ads from your network . Embed the URL in the web browser control in your WPF applications. This would work on condition that the desktop is connected to internet all the time.

In case if all doors are closed , and you still want to make money from your wpf app , you can think about using toolbars provided by various vendors in your application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't use Amazon Product Advertising API, because it can be used only if my app [have as their principal purpose advertising and marketing the Amazon Site and driving sales of products and services on the Amazon Site](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/agreement.html?ie=UTF8&pf_rd_t=501&ref_=amb_link_83952631_8&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=&pf_rd_s=assoc-center-1&pf_rd_r=&pf_rd_i=assoc-api-detail-0)

Comment: What is the advertising domain you are looking for ?

Comment: I'm looking for simple advertising service (like Google Ads) for .NET/WPF.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some term you may encounter while your start your research in the marketing jungle. you can imagine the Marketplace of advertisement like WallStreet, it work with bidding.

open market : you may get X ads. Ads that lock the user navigation or else... it's a mess.

private market : elitist, you better have good arguments!

---

Publisher : probably YOU, your website, your application

Advertiser : generally brands

SSP : Supply-Side Platforms (for Publishers)

DSP : Demand-Side Platform (for Advertisers)

RTB : Real-Time Bidding (used by all open market)

PMP : Private Marketplace

Programmatic Direct : mostly used by PMP to ease advertisers<>publishers targeting & bidding

Inventory : ads Demands/Supplies

Impression : ads showed by publishers on a webpage/application

---

Ad Exchange: marketplace for SSP, DSP, Ad Network & other Ad exchange to buy/sell ad inventory

ex: Google Ad Manager (Google DoubleClick Ad Exchange) < this one is a PMP

---

Ad Network : (optionnal mediator / PMP)

ex: Google AdSense, Facebook Audience Network, Microsoft Advertising, Amazon Associates, openX, etc...

---

Ad Mediation (optionnal mediator working with multiple Ad Network)

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

With all of that, you may still wonder why desktop application is not accepted by the PMP?
there's a lot of reason, but here are some:

- You are unknow and brands don't want to take the risk to be associated with a hacking tool or other illegal stuff
- mobile phone app is accepted coz they are all validated by a human review before been released in the "blabla store". So, advertiser don't need to worry too much about the quality of the publisher.

My advise is that if you want to be in business with a PMP, then you're going to have to prove yourself. Build a website (and put ads in it), publish your application, build a reputation, write mails, call phones, negotiate.

And i sincerly whish you to succeed!