# How to implement Ads in Desktop Application built with WPF or Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, wpf, ads, windowsformsintegration

I would like to implement like as it comes in Utorrent/Skype.

I looked forward to lot of options. Here is the list:

- Google Adsense
- Microsoft Pub Center
- Desktopad -- Communicated with them and got the answer that it is only for Windows Store Apps.
- Bing Ads -- Not sure whether this will work or not. But I don't have any one to provide ads in my application. I need any Ad-Network company to send Ads in an application. So i don't think Bing Ads will work for me.
- Smaato Ads

Thought of using Google Adsense by implementing in Website and fetching in application. But after referring one of the article listed below -- I came to know that they might block an account. So ignored that idea, as this is not the correct approach.

Referred Links -

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0efce3f9-74ec-4dc6-86af-d64111913884/advertise-in-wpf-application?forum=wpf

[Advertise in WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068103/advertise-in-wpf-application)

Also referred lot of other links via Stack Overflow and other mediums. But none of it helped me in getting this done.

Few questions which comes to me -

- How Utorrent and Skype provide Ads? -- These are also desktop applications.
- Which Ad-Network they use?

Comment: I'm quite sure that Skype uses its own ad network provided by Microsoft itself

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone is finding the question:

At least for google there are APIs:
https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-dotnet

Probably the other ad providers also have similar APIs.